# How to check whether an app receives and displays push notifications or not programmatically?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-permissions

Is is possible to check whether an app receives and displays push notifications to the user screen or not, programmatically?

Currently, I am using below code to get the list of installed apps on the phone.

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(   mainIntent, 0);
```

**How to filter the above result to obtain a list of only the push notification receiving/displaying apps?** Can this be done by checking which permissions the app uses? Please provide a code sample for the same.

Comment: Apps don't send push notifications, they receive them. What you mean are just notifications.

Comment: I mean the apps for which notifications are displayed on the notification bar such as Whatsapp, Clash of Clans to name a few.

Comment: Just to clarify: there're two separate pieces there that is making your question not very clear: 1) is the Google Cloud Message GCM (or the newer Firebase Cloud Message FCM) and 2) is showing notifications on the screen. Those are two different and independent things. An app can use the push to perfom sync and a different app can show notifications with a timer. What is your question about?

Comment: Just to add: To detect GCM it's probably possible. To detect if an app shows notifications, you can only detect after a notifications was shown.

Comment: @Budius : Please provide an answer considering both cases separately. I have to consider all possibilities. Thanks for you time. Very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm super busy now but here's the TL;DR: `Receive GCM/FCM`: query the package manager to find packages that contains a `receiver` with the correct `intent-filter` to receive pushes (see official docs https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client for the intent filter). `Check notifications`: Use a `NotificationListenerService` to listen for any notifications as they are posted on to the NotificationManager (official docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)

Comment: PS.: you query PackageManager to find who can receive Push using `queryBroadcastReceivers` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryBroadcastReceivers(android.content.Intent, int)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Budius